# Injecting Abstract Stateless bean in another stateless bean

Tags: jpa, ejb, java-ee-6, abstraction, stateless

I am using java ee to develop 1 abstract module Hospital and two children modules Lab and Radioligy each module is seperate project.. Since Lab and Radiology have many common functionalities and common beans then i develop an abstract parent project that contains the common beans and facades.. But the entities with their relations are a bit different for example in radioligy there is an entity called invoice that contains Machine object while in lab the invoice entity does not contain, and the common beans are using the entities and relations. what is the best way to deal with such abstraction knowing that when I put all common entities and common stateless beans  in Hospital module.I defined them as abstract.. But when injecting one to another it is failing on deploy with message(no such ejb...)

Is there any optimal way for my abstraction..